# HTML/server function interaction (GET, POST)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I think I'm lacking some understanding of these fundamental concepts (I've read a decent amount of resources and examples) of how these functions work server-side and how the html interacts with them.  I was writing methods earlier today and communicating between the server and html perfectly, manipulating an array I had stored locally on the server file.  For reference I'll show you how I was doing it.

**jQuery script in html file:**

```
$.post("/deck", { name: "Angel of Fury", power: 666 }, function(){

});
```

**server file:**

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        db = require('./db'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        controller = require('./controller');

    //add body parser middleware
    app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
      extended: true
    })); 


    //Serves static pages
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + ('/')));

    //loads the html page
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


    var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
      var host = server.address().address;
      host = (host === '::' ? 'localhost' : host);
      var port = server.address().port;

      console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });

      var deck = [ ];

      app.get('/deck', function(req, res) {
          res.send(deck);
      });

      app.post('/deck', function(req, res) {
          console.log(req.body);
          var card = req.body;
          deck.push(card);
          res.send(deck);
      });
```

Given this code I could navigate to "localhost:3000/deck and any changes I made were stored in the array and displayed at this address.  Simple enough.  I've taken that a step farther and implemented a database, mySQL and have successfully written methods for insertion, select, delete, etc..

```
    <script>
$("submit").on("click", function(){
        $.post("/users", { name: username.value, password: psw.value, email: email.value}, function(){
            console.log("post successful..");
        });
    });
   </script>

    <body>
    <form>
            username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="psw"><br>
            email:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

I added the above form jquery script to the html page.  And attempted to add the server functions below.

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

});

app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I thought that this would allow me to use the **req.body** object on submission of the form.  Please correct me if I'm going about this the wrong way, I would be grateful for any help/tips.

Comment: In your server, are you seeing the logged response of your `app.post('users')` callback when you post to the `/users` endpoint?

Comment: No, I'm thinking that the function isn't even getting hit.

Comment: Is `$.post('/users')` being called correctly when `$("submit").on("click")` is called (check your network tab in dev tools to confirm)?

Comment: I don't see any errors.  Also I have a console.log in the jquery callback to verify it's success, and I'm not getting any console messages.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, all technical problems aside, am I going about this the right way?  The data I get from the form is going to be sent to a mySQL database.

Comment: Strange, and your `app.get('/users')` callback is getting executed if you send a `GET` request to the `/users` endpoint? I can't see anything wrong with the code you have posted. Maybe it's a problem on the network end?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/?username=&psw=&email=

this is what I get when I click submit.  Im guessing its trying to post.

Comment: That URL has a query string in it (`?username=&psw=&email=`), which suggests that it's not actually making a `POST` request. Can you screenshot your network tab?

Comment: How would I add a screenshot ?

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw Where do you define `username.value`, `psw.value` and  email.value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.
2. Change the button type to button instead.

As you have not prevented the form to submit so, whenever you click the submit button it submits the form and it makes a default get request if method attribute to post is not been provided.

```
 $("submit").on("click", function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();  // <--------  HERE
    $.post("/users", { name: username.value, password: psw.value, email: email.value}, function(){
        console.log("post successful..");
    });
 });
```

Or make a small change at your markup:

```
<input type="button"....../>
```

In the form.

As per your latest comment, add a class/id attribute to the button and change the selector:

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit"...../>
```

Now in js you have to use this:

```
 $("#submit") // <---- notice the # which denotes the ID selector in jQuery.
```

Comment: What do you mean by stopping the form submission?  I want the form to submit the information.  Sorry, I'm a newb.

Comment: Updating...! But in short you have to do this in your js code.

Comment: Where would I add the preventDefault method?

Comment: I added preventDefault right after the onclick jquery script, changed the input type to button, and now the button just seems completely dead.

Comment: Okay now I can see one more change to do. Add a class or ID attribute to your button and use that in the code.

Comment: I've made all the suggested changes.  The button is still dead.

Comment: My user endpoint may be useless as well.

I've added a console.log to the get method and when I access the localhost:3000/users I get no console messages.  However It also doesn't tell me that it "Cannot GET /users" which it will do if I access any other endpoint.

Comment: Bro, out of curiosity, is your answer working? As there is no any HTML tag submit, what will your jquery selector $('submit') select? May be what you need is $('input[type=submit]') or something else...

Comment: Actually I take that back.  For some reason It's abruptly stopped working.  I'm guessing whatever is causing this issue is my main concern.

Comment: I've tried adding classes and id's for the selector.  I think the problem lies elsewhere, in the endpoint definition.  I can't access localhost:3000/users now.  I'm not sure what caused this to JUST NOW start acting up.

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw Have you restarted your node application after you made changes to the code? Sounds like a stupid question, but i failed on that a lot. Remember: The `serverside` JavaScript needs a restart to reflect any changes, while the `clientside` javaScript does not need any restart!

Comment: Yes I try restarting every time.  This is getting really frustrating.  I've used jQuery way too much to not be able to click a single button make something happen.